# Duplicar formulario horizontalmente jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

actualmente tengo un archivo HTML que cuando lo imprimo sale asi

```
Fecha

Descrpción

Patente

Fecha

Descrpción

Patente
```

Hice el siguiente código para duplicar el formulario

```
function impresionEspecial(){
            var win = window.open("", "Titulo página", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=200, height=100, top=0, left=0");
            var formulario = document.getElementById('form_duplicar').innerHTML;
            win.document.body.innerHTML = formulario + '' + formulario+ '' + formulario;
            win.print();
            win.close();
        };
```

Necesito poder imprimir tres copias en la misma hoja, pero lo necesito horizontal y como observan se ve vertical, cómo podría poner el duplicado horizontal?, la necesitaría asi:

```
                    Fecha      Fecha      Fecha
               Descrpción Descrpción Descrpción
               Patente    Patente    Patente
```

Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme

Comment: Usa tablas, cabe recalcar que estos elementos no son responsive

Comment: Gracias pero no lo veo necesario, ya lo tengo todo cuadrado necesitaría es saber como duplicarlo horizontalmente

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el `html` que estas empleando? y de ser posible el `css` también.